# Camera.main is not what the user sees

Tags: unity, c#

I'm developing (or rather butchering) plugin for Rust, which was build in Unity,  and I need to create a targeting system. Unfortunately I got stuck on `WorldToScreenPoint` and `WorldToViewportPoint`. It seems that the `Camera.main` is not what player sees and is not moving at all. Also it has different resolution from what the game is set up.

Unfortunately I can't use Unity and all the work needs to be done in VS.

Does anyone has a suggestion how to get a "proper" camera for this?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

As requested this is my code: `Debug.log(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(bAnimalNPC.transform.position).x.ToString())`
`Debug.log(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(bAnimalNPC.transform.position).y.ToString())`
`Debug.log(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(bAnimalNPC.transform.position).z.ToString())`

The rest is just getting the `bAnimalNPC` and doing some checks.

Comment: Can you get a list of all cameras in the scene with FindObjectsOfType<Camera> and investigate whether the player's view camera has any distinguishing characteristics?

Comment: I've tried listing all cameras present but I've used different method and it returned only Camera.main. I'll try FindObjectsOfType<Camera> to see if it will give me same result. Question - is it possible that there is only one camera? I mean logically players eyes should be a camera too.

Comment: I have finally got time to check this and there is only one camera in the scene - Camera.main. So it must be player view camera. This however raises a question why WorldToViewportPoint and WorldToScreenPoint calculate values wrong, e.g. if the object I'm trying to target does not move (but the player does) the values do not change. When the target moves but I follow it with my "eyes" the values change. I'm missing something out but i don't know what...

Comment: @Wujaszkun Is the camera viewing the animal?

Comment: It's an fps so look from my character eyes.

Comment: Reading through all the answers/comments so far, I wonder if Rust just has a very unintuitive camera setup. What about [getting the active scene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html) and printing out the entire hierarchy by [iterating the transforms](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.GetRootGameObjects.html)? This might shed some light on what "camera" you're actually seeing through.

Answer (score 4):

### Main Camera

`main` is a property of `Camera` that returns

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
```

Which is not really performant and you need to cache it in a variable at the start, but with that said, you could just tag your desired camera with `MainCamera` tag and it works.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html

### Current Camera

You can also get the `current` camera which unity is currently rendering, like this:

```
Camera.current
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-current.html

### All Cameras

If you can't access the unity scene, you could get all the cameras in the scene via code and check if it's your desired camera.

you can get all enabled cameras in the scene, using this :

```
Camera.allCameras
```

Which returns `Camera[]`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-allCameras.html

### EDIT

Put this code on the animal and see what happens:

```
void OnGUI(){
    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
    Debug.Log(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).x.ToString());
    GUI.Box(new Rect(screenPos.x - 30, (Screen.height - screenPos.y) - 15, 60, 30), "Text");
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried Camera.allCameras and it returned only one camera: Main So this didn't work for me. As for the Camera.current it is read-only and afaik only for use in specific situations.

Comment: is the ```Camera``` returned by ```allCameras``` tagged "MainCamera"? use ```Debug.Log(Camera.allCameras[0].CompareTag("MainCamera"));```

Comment: Yep it's the `MainCamera`, and there are no other cameras according to `Camera.allCameras`.

Comment: @Wujaszkun I guess there is something else wrong with what you're doing, please edit your question and insert your  ```WorldToScreenPoint``` and ```WorldToViewportPoint``` code which is the real issue.

Comment: As requested I have added my code.

Comment: @Wujaszkun what do you get from those debug.logs

Comment: I'm getting values for x and y but the don't change as I move my mouse. The change when the animal moves.

Comment: @Wujaszkun where did you place the code you shared in the edit?

Answer (score 1):

Mohammed Zamanian explained a lot already, but let me provide you with a generic, practical solution.

You should create a Singleton class, which you put on an invisible gameObject on your scene. Assign your main camera to a public Camera variable. If you use multiple ones, with a fixed amount, use multiple variables.

```
public class CameraManager
{
    public static CameraManager Instance;

    // Refer to these by "CameraManager.Instance.PrimaryCamera"
    public Camera PrimaryCamera; // Remember to assign the camera on the gameObject.
    public Camera SecondaryCamera; // Assign this too.

    public Camera CurrentCamera; // This is your currently active camera set by the methods below.

    protected void Awake ()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void ActivatePrimaryCamera ()
    {
        CurrentCamera = PrimaryCamera;
        SecondaryCamera.enabled = false; // Do the camera transition here.
        PrimaryCamera.enabled = true;
    }

    public void ActivateSecondaryCamera ()
    {
        CurrentCamera = SecondaryCamera;
        PrimaryCamera.enabled = false; // Do the camera transition here.
        SecondaryCamera.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Now you can set your camera as the current camera and can efficiently refer to them with your own code. I advise you to assert control over your cameras, so that you don't just arbitrarily search for whatever is currently active, and always know which one is active.

The Unity camera functions should be seen as backup functions, as they are not performant. Do not use them unless necessary. Rely on your own code.